# How to find out valid values for an option

Tags: front-end, options, customization

In Mathematica 11.0 I want to temporarily change the behavior of error messages via code.

[image: user interface log messages option in settings menu]

I tried the following code:

```
(* Disable warnings, but "Ignore" is not a valid value *)
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, MessageOptions -> {"ConsoleMessageAction" -> "Ignore"}]
(* do some stuff... *)
(* re-enable warnings, "PrintToConsole" is a valid value *)
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, MessageOptions -> {"ConsoleMessageAction" -> "PrintToConsole"}]
```

Re-enabling works, but I can't turn the warnings off. The first command gives the error message

> The specified setting for the option MessageOptions, ConsoleMessageAction cannot be used.

How can I find out the proper value for `"ConsoleMessageAction"` for setting it to `Ignore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe what changes when you set it to `Ignore`:

```
Dynamic @ CurrentValue[
   $FrontEnd, {MessageOptions, "ConsoleMessageAction"}
]
```

And you will see that the corresponding value is an empty list: `{}`;

Another way would be to parse the content of the Preferences.nb dialog but that wasn't necessary here.