# How to temporarily turn off log messages?

Tags: gui-construction, java

I'm using GUIKit in Mathematica 11.0, which throws an error message whenever a window or panel is shown. I know GUIKit is deprecated but I don't want to port a whole project to the newer controls.

Now I want to suppress the error messages coming from GUIKit but keep all other possible messages. `Quiet` sadly doesn't work. I thought I could change the setting `User interface log messages` to `Ignore` temporarily, switch to another panel and re-enable the messages again (see [How to find out valid values for an option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141700/how-to-find-out-valid-values-for-an-option)).

However it doesn't work and I can't see why. I used the following code snippet:

```
Unprotect[System`PropertyValue];
Remove[System`PropertyValue];
Needs["GUIKit`"]

frm = Widget["Frame", {
WidgetGroup[{
  Widget["Panel", {
    "visible" -> False,
    BindEvent["ComponentShown", 
     Script[SetPropertyValue[{"frmHauptfenster", "title"}, 
        "Panel 1"];]],

    Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Panel 1"}],
    Widget["Button", {
      "text" -> "toggle1",
      BindEvent["action", Script[ToggleVisible[];]]}
     ]
    }, Name -> "p1"],
  Widget["Panel", {
    "visible" -> True, 
    BindEvent["ComponentShown", 
     Script[SetPropertyValue[{"frmHauptfenster", "title"}, 
        "Panel 2"];]],

    Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Panel 2"}],
    Widget["Button", {
      "text" -> "toggle2",
      BindEvent["action", Script[ToggleVisible[];]]}
     ]
    }, Name -> "p2"]
  }, WidgetLayout -> {"Border" -> 5, 
   "Stretching" -> {Maximize, Maximize}}]
, Script[
 ToggleVisible[] := Module[{},
    (* Turn off messages *)
    SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
     MessageOptions -> {"ConsoleMessageAction" -> {}}];
    p1visible = PropertyValue[{"p1", "Visible"}];
    SetPropertyValue[{"p1", "Visible"}, Not[p1visible]];
    SetPropertyValue[{"p2", "Visible"}, p1visible];
    (* Turn messages back on *)
    SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
     MessageOptions -> {"ConsoleMessageAction" -> 
        "PrintToConsole"}];
    ];
 ]
}, Name -> "frmHauptfenster"];



ref = GUIRun[frm];
```

Why doesn't it work? Or is there even another workaround?